# How to update a date variable by adding a month in Javascript

Tags: javascript

how do i add a month to my date constant?

my variable receives an input with the date format I want to take this variable and each click add an extra month to it

I've tried using the gets and sets and nothing so far, like this : .getMonth()

I solved it, I created a function and added a stepUp that when I click on the button it adds days and it looks like this for example:
 `function dateFunction() { document.getElementById("myDate").stepUp(30); }`

Comment: Post a [mcve], `Date()` is tricky and we need to know to what exactly your variable is assigned to and the nature of your event handler (JavaScript and HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do it for you.

```js
function addMonth(date, numMonthsToAdd) {
  const newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + numMonthsToAdd));

  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work in my case as i said i get a variable i just want to add one more month

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? Could you not add one more month with this function?

Answer (score 0):

This should add 1 more month to you Date:

```
function addOneMonth(date) {
  const newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1));

  return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel getMonth should solve your problem assuming the input date is a date-type variable. Just wrote a sample code for the same.

```js
let inputDate = new Date();

function addMonth(date) {
  const newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1));

  return newDate;
}

inputDate = addMonth(inputDate)

console.log('input date', inputDate)
```